# how to improve this code with try-catch exceptions

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

I have this java code which is a part of a managed bean which is used to display data from database into JSF table.

```
//connect to DB and get customer list
public List<Dashboard> getDashboardList() throws SQLException {

    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
    }

    //get database connection
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();

    if (con == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS");

    //get customer data from database
    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    List<Dashboard> list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();

    while (result.next()) {
        Dashboard cust = new Dashboard();

        cust.setUser(result.getString("SessionTTL"));
        cust.setPassword(result.getString("MAXACTIVEUSERS"));


        //store all data into a List
        list.add(cust);
    }
    ps.close();
    con.close();
    return list;        
}
```

I want to improve this code and insert try catch statements. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I don't totally understand the question. Put try/catch around the clumps of code that can generate them, like you've already done for some. The comments aren't that useful, btw.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: What will (or rather, will not) happen if `ps.executeQuery()` throws an `SQLException`? Will `ps.close()` or `con.close()` ever be called? Consider that and determine how using `try`/`catch`/`finally` might help fix it.

Comment: some info here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/closing_and_releasing_jdbc_resources.html

Comment: you know, we have a site for this kind of question--[codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to improve this code with try-catch exeptions?

You can review your question title, since you are not asking about **improvement**, but maybe **organizing.** Based on your code, I changed your method so that it looks cleaner and more organized about catching exceptions.

```
public List<Dashboard> getDashboardList(DataSource ds)
{   
    List<Dashboard> list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try
    {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS");
        //get customer data from database
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        while (result.next())
        {
            Dashboard cust = new Dashboard();
            cust.setUser(result.getString("SessionTTL"));
            cust.setPassword(result.getString("MAXACTIVEUSERS"));
            list.add(cust);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        // Log the exception.
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
             if(ps != null)
                  ps.close();
             if(con != null)
                  con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e2)
        {
            // Log the exception.
        }
    }
    return list; 
}
```

Comment: The `ps.close` and `con.close` may throw an exception, you want to surround those in a try catch block as well.

Comment: @maple_shaft thank you, i have missed that point, corrected my code now.

Comment: @user1103606 i reviewed my code corrected some mistakes, take a look at it and also in your question remove your updated code because it already appears in the answers, readers may find your question too long.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do that? If any error occurs, the method doesn't really have what to do, so it seems appropriate to throw an exception in those cases.

The only thing I would change is adding a finally method, to close connections:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS");

    //get customer data from database
    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    List<Dashboard> list = new ArrayList<Dashboard>();

    while (result.next()) {
        Dashboard cust = new Dashboard();

        cust.setUser(result.getString("SessionTTL"));
        cust.setPassword(result.getString("MAXACTIVEUSERS"));


        //store all data into a List
        list.add(cust);
    }
}
finally {
    ps.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: The close methods can throw an exception, you want to wrap those in try catch as well.

Comment: One `try-finally` per resource! `Resource resource = acquire(); try { resource.use(); } finally { resource.release(); }` or in current Java,`try (Resource resource = acquire()) { resource.use(); }`, or use the Execute Around idiom. In this particular example `ps` will be out of scope, and `ResultSet` should be explicitly closed.

Comment: ps is not visible in the finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by proper, but if you remove the top `throws SQLException` from your method, your IDE will display a tooltip for any non caught exception, and you can auto-insert each of the missing ones that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic Java stuff so I recommend picking up a book and learning the basics.  Regardless, I typically do something like the following

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
  // DB code
} catch (SQLException se) {
  log.error("Experienced SQLException in method foo", se);
  FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Oops!  You messed up!", null);
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
} finally {
  if (conn != null && conn.isOpen()) {
    try {
      conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException see) {
      log.error("Connection can't be closed!");
      // Faces message or something like it
    }
}
```